# Cant navigate to specific page in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, nativescript, angular-routing

I cant navigate o specific page in my angular app, in this case i want to navigate to `(tabs/market-palce/fornecedores)` from app.component.ts here my routing Modules.

```
 Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs/market-palce/fornecedores'
```

and if go from other page thats not app.component.hmtl and print the url it show this

```
/tabs/default/(marketTab:market-place/fornecedores//cartoesTab:cartoes/default//profileTab:profile/default//experienciaTab:experiencia/default)
```

How could i go to fornedores page from app.component.ts ???

How could i make this work?? i have no ideia.

im trying this in app.comoponent.ts

```
 this.routerExtensions.navigate(['tabs/market-place/fornecedores', { relativeTo: this.activeRoute });
```

app.routing

```
    const routes: Routes = [

        {   path: "",
            redirectTo: "/login",
            pathMatch: "full"
        },

        {   path: "login",
            component: LoginComponent
        },

        {
            path: "tabs",
            loadChildren: "~/app/tabs/tabs.module#TabsModule"
        }
]
```

tabs routing

```
const routes: Routes = [

    {
        path: "default", component: TabsComponent, children: [


            {
                path: "market-place",
                component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                loadChildren: "~/app/market-place/market-place.module#MarketPlaceModule",
                outlet: "marketTab"
            },
            {
                path: "cartoes",
                component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                loadChildren: "~/app/cartoes/cartoes.module#CartoesModule",
                outlet: "cartoesTab"
            },
            {
                path: "profile",
                component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                loadChildren: "~/app/profile/profile.module#ProfileModule",
                outlet: "profileTab"
            },
            {
                path: "experiencia",
                component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                loadChildren: "~/app/experiencia/experiencia.module#ExperienciaModule",
                outlet: "experienciaTab"
            }
        ]
     }
];
```

market-place Routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: "", redirectTo: "default" },
    {path: "default", component: MarketPlaceComponent},
    {path: "fornecedores", component: FornecedoresComponent }

];
```

Comment: Have you added <router-outlet></router-outlet> tag to app.component.ts?

Comment: yes i did add it

Comment: None of my routes start with ~/app, all of mine start with app. ~/ is usually the node modules folder.

Comment: You could try Angular 8, it uses the new import syntax for lazy loading modules.

Comment: ~/app in this case is because im using angular in nativescript

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration)

```
{   path: "",
    redirectTo: "/login",
    pathMatch: "full"
},
```

to the end of the array.

> Technically, pathMatch = 'full' results in a route hit when the remaining, unmatched segments of the URL match ''. In this example, the redirect is in a top level route so the remaining URL and the entire URL are the same thing.
>
> The other possible pathMatch value is 'prefix' which tells the router
>   to match the redirect route when the remaining URL begins with the
>   redirect route's prefix path.
>
> Don't do that here. If the pathMatch value were 'prefix', every URL
>   would match ''.
>
> Try setting it to 'prefix' then click the Go to sidekicks button.
>   Remember that's a bad URL and you should see the "Page not found"
>   page. Instead, you're still on the "Heroes" page. Enter a bad URL in
>   the browser address bar. You're instantly re-routed to /heroes. Every
>   URL, good or bad, that falls through to this route definition will be
>   a match.
>
> The default route should redirect to the HeroListComponent only when
>   the entire url is ''. Remember to restore the redirect to pathMatch =
>   'full'.
>
> Learn more in Victor Savkin's post on redirects.

Answer (score 0):

### Configuration

First I suppose you are being redirected to the `login` route or page. It's quite normal.

When angular matches paths, the `""` comes first, which redirects on the `"/login"`, after what the `"login"` and then the `"tabs"`.

Your problem is that the route `""` matches with every route, even `"tabs"` so you're always redirected to the `/login` path.

You may then need to place the empty path at the end, such as:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {   
      path: "login",
      component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
      path: "tabs",
      loadChildren: "~/app/tabs/tabs.module#TabsModule"
  }
  {   
      path: "",
      redirectTo: "/login",
      pathMatch: "full"
  },
]
```

(Personally I usually use `"**"` instead of `""` because I want to be aware that It's the end of my roads, and to be redirected on unknowns paths)

You can read more about all these tricks on [the official documentation's page](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration).

### Navigation

Now if you want to navigate, you should use the `Router`-service and give the path.

You may use the absolute path to be faster, like using

`/tabs/market-palce/fornecedores`

instead of

`tabs/market-palce/fornecedores`.

(Notice the `/`at the beginning)

```
constructor(
   ...
   private router: Router,
   ...
) {...}

navigateToTabs() {
   const path = '/tabs/market-palce/fornecedores'
   this.router.navigate([path]); // <-- Here the is your path
}
```

You may also want to learn more ways of navigating using angular [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#navigating-back-to-the-list-component), again on [the official documentation's page](https://angular.io/guide/router#navigating-back-to-the-list-component)

Comment: did not work `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs/market-palce/fornecedores'`

Comment: First I don't recommend you using `outlet` with `loadModule`. Then, please what is the content of `~/app/market-place/market-place.module#MarketPlaceModule` ?

Comment: the content of MarketPlaceModule  its on the post

Comment: Then I suppose you'll be using `/tabs/default(marketTab:market-place)/fornecedores` because you're using `outlet`, and the default path in `tabs`is `default`.